# How to write a post-receive hook that accepts chmod changes?

Tags: git

When I chmod a file and try to merge this change with my master repo, it doesn't work: the permissions I set in my local repo do not propagate to master.

Do I need a post-receive hook? What should the contents of that file be exactly?

Comment: Git does not track permissions beyond the executable bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by writing a post-commit hook that chmods all of the files in a directory. This is not exactly what I was aiming for because it indiscriminately chmods all files in the directory instead of just the ones I changed in the local commit, but it works well enough.

Comment: I think it is better to use pre-commit hook because changing executable bit change a content of the directory and that changes the commit.